# Draggable table with the parent-child relationship

Tags: forms

I have a draggable table with a parent-child relationship, where the children can be moved between parents, but cannot be moved onto the parent position. So in sum, the child can change the parent, but cannot become a parent.

```
Parent 1
  - child x
  - child y
Parent 2
  - child z
```

According to [drupal_add_tabledrag()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7) I added the following classes:

All the parents have a `tabledrag-root` class, so they cannot be nested under a parent row.
All the children have a `tabledrag-leaf` class, so they cannot have any child rows.

The problem is that, it doesn't work if the child is `the last one` or `the only one`, so both `child y` and `child z` can be dragged onto parent position.

How to prevent all the child items from being moved onto the parent position?

Comment: What I did was simply to disable changing of depth for all elements in table. Can't see now how exactly I did it, as I have the codes on my other computer. root and leaf approach was pretty much useless for me too, for the same reasons.

Comment: Tomorrow will have a chance